# Find probability of Rodrigo bringing $1$ or $2$ or $3$ shirts of different colors

Tags: probability

I am stuck with a simple question in probability and would appreciate your help. The question is:

> In a clothing shop, there are infinitely many white, red and blue shirts. In each time Rodrigo is asked, he brings a white shirt with probability $0.4$, a red one with probability $0.5$ and a blue one with probability $0.1$. Three guys enter the shop and for each one Rodrigo brings a shirt.
>
> Let $X$ denote the number of different colors of shirts Rodrigo brought.

This is what I did:

- first of all, $X\in \{1,2,3\}$ because either Rodrigo brings all the three shirts from the same color, or he can bring 2 shirts the same color, and also he can bring 3 different shirts in their color.
- $P(X=1)=(\frac{5}{10})^3+(\frac{4}{10})^3+(\frac{1}{10})^3$ - or three red shirts, or three white or three blue.
- $P(X=3)=(\frac{5}{10})(\frac{4}{10})(\frac{1}{10})$ - each shirt from different color
- $P(X=2)=1-P(X=1)-P(X=3)=0.79$

  - in other way if I calculate $P(X=2)$, **I get a different answer though it shouldnt differ and I can't find the reason!** => $$P(X=2)=(\frac{5}{10})^2((\frac{4}{10})+(\frac{1}{10}))+(\frac{4}{10})^2((\frac{5}{10})+(\frac{1}{10}))+(\frac{1}{10})^2((\frac{5}{10})+(\frac{4}{10}))=0.23\ne0.79$$

Answer (score 1):

Your $P(X=3)$ is low by a factor $3!=6$ because he could bring the shirts in any order.  Then your direct computation of $P(X=2)$ is low by a factor $3$ because there are three ways to order two shirts of one color and one of another.  These corrections make the problem disappear.

Comment: so even if I have two red shirts - they still differ? thus their order is important?

Comment: No, but if you have two red and one blue there are  three orders to put them in.

Comment: Oh now I got you! thanks so much. so for X=3 I have got all the possible permutations (3!) and for X=2 I should multiply by $\binom{3}{1}$ to choose destination for the shirt of the different color..

Comment: Yes, that is correct.